# How customize Bootstrap 4 with grid and justify-content classes only?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I flag all the options on the bootstrap 4 customize page there are no "justify-content" classes.

Comment: Would you be able to show some code of what you're referring to?

Comment: What code? I need download Bootstrap 4 only with grid and aligning classes.